The key does not match any row in the table - SSAS/PBI
I created a SSAS model in Visual Studio and deployed it to QA. But then I am facing an issue saying that:

The key does not match any row in the table.. Key=(Schema="view",
Item="TablesName". Table=#table({"Name", "Data", "Schema", "Item",
"Kind"}. {}) The key does not match any row in the table..

The only way I found to fix this is when I go to SSAS and update my credentials manually, but doing this I stop the automatic update.
When I was developing the model, I changed the table and the model names, but I checked the names and found no mismatch between dev and QA.
I also took the first version of the model and deployed it, I have already rebuilt the model from scratch, I have already deployed one table at a time or used different tables, added and removed the relationship, but no sucess.
Another model in a different DB when I deploy works fine, but this model and another in this DB are having this issue. I also do not have the Entra ID P2 license, I don't know if this is related or not and I don't use any Excel file in the model. And I have access to the QA.
I would appreciate if anyone could give me some insigths what I could try different or direct me in the right way.

The solution was to correct the credentials registered in the database. When the model was implemented with credentials that differed from those in the database, the model was unable to access the tables in the database.
